# From 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote this program on IDLE 2.7 by mistake (I am a beginner).
Now I am trying to run it in 3.4 I get errors, I went on an made changes but I am still not able to run it. any help?
Yes the code might not even be great but I am still working on it. So any help will be greatly appreciated.
For me I thought only parentheses were the major difference between both updates.

```
# Convert a decimal to a hex as a string 
def decimalToHex(decimalValue):
    hex = ""

    while decimalValue != 0:
        hexValue = int(decimalValue) % 16 
        hex = toHexChar(hexValue) + hex
        decimalValue = int(decimalValue) // 16    
    return hex

def printRect (row_count, col_count):   
    row = []
    column = []    
    for r in range(row_count):        
        row = []
        column = []
        end_row_flag = 'False'        
        for c in range(col_count):
            if r % (row_count) == 0:
                if c % (col_count-1) == 0:
                    row.append('+')
                else:
                    row.append('-')                        
                    end_row_flag = 'True'        
            if end_row_flag == 'True':
                end_row = row        
            if c % (col_count-1) == 0:
                column.append('|')            
            else:
                column.append(' ')                
        if row:
            print (row)        
        print (column)                
    print (end_row)    

def charASCII(letter):    
    return (ord(letter))

# Convert an integer to a single hex digit in a character 
def toHexChar(hexValue):
    if 0 <= hexValue <= 9:
        return chr(hexValue + ord('0'))
    else:  # 10 <= hexValue <= 15
        return chr(hexValue - 10 + ord('A'))


def main():
    # Prompt the user to enter a decimal integer        
    data_file = []
    char_file = []
    ascii_file = []  
    hex_key = []
    decimal_key = []
    nonkey_val = 32
    data_file.append(' Dec   Hex  Char ')
    data_file.append('+---------------+')
    for i in range(nonkey_val):
        a_char = chr(i)
        hex_convert = decimalToHex(i)
        if i < 10:
            decimal_key = '0%s' % i
        else:
            decimal_key = '%s' % i        
        if i <= 15:            
            hex_key = '0%s' % hex_convert
        else:            
            hex_key = hex_convert
        data_file.append('| %s   %s   %s |' % (decimal_key.strip(), hex_key.strip(), a_char))
        # data_file.append('%s' % (a_char))

    with open ('sample_file.txt', 'r') as f:                       
        data = f.readlines()                  
        for character in data:                        
            print ('character is %s' % character)               
            decimalValue = charASCII(character[0])             
            hex_convert = decimalToHex(decimalValue)            
            print ('decimalValue is %s' % decimalValue)                                    
            print ('The hex number for decimal %s is %s' % (decimalValue, hex_convert)                                                
            data_file.append('| %s   %s   %s |' % (decimalValue, hex_convert.strip(), character.strip())))                                            
    data_file.append('+---------------+')
    print data_file    
    f.close()

    with open ('output_file.txt', 'w+') as o:
        for line in data_file:
            o.write('%s\n'% line)
    o.close 




main() # Call the main function
rows = input("Enter the numer of rows: ")    
columns = input("Enter the number of columns: ")    
printRect (rows, columns)
```

Comment: And what errors are you getting? Can you reduce your code to *just* the parts that have problems?

Comment: Tip for the future: if you want to port your (working) code from Python 2.x to 3.x, then the `2to3` tool can do 90% of the work for you. In some cases, you won't even need to hand edit anything.

Answer (score 0):

You had three typos which if you provided the traceback and the relevant piece of code it happened in would have made it more obvious.

```
with open ('sample_file.txt', 'r') as f:                       
    data = f.readlines()                  
    for character in data:                        
        print ('character is %s' % character)               
        decimalValue = charASCII(character[0])             
        hex_convert = decimalToHex(decimalValue)            
        print ('decimalValue is %s' % decimalValue)                                    
        print ('The hex number for decimal %s is %s' % (decimalValue, hex_convert) )# missing paren here
        data_file.append('| %s   %s   %s |' % (decimalValue, hex_convert.strip(), character.strip())) # had extra paren here
data_file.append('+---------------+')
print(data_file  ) # missing parens
```

with closes your files so you don't need to manually but if you were it would be `o.close()` not `o.close`

I would also you an actual boolean not a string "True":

```
      end_row_flag = True       
   if end_row_flag:
```

Comment: a syntax error with data_file highlighted.
 print ('The hex number for decimal %s is %s' % (decimalValue, hex_convert)                                                
            data_file.append('| %s   %s   %s |' % (decimalValue, hex_convert.strip(), character.strip())))

Comment: the error is from later lines, the code I posted is the corrected version